# SQL server copy paste no column breaks

Tags: sql-server, excel, copy-paste

I have a very simple query in MS SQL Server 2016.  I have been using 'Select All', 'Copy With Headers' and pasting the results into Excel.  The results parse out perfectly into the correct columns with headers.  I've been doing this for over a year with no problem.  For the past 2 days, though, the data is not split into the right columns, but comes over as one long string.  There are no spaces, tabs or other delimiters that would allow me to parse the data after pasting it into Excel.  Because this was working fine before, I have to wonder if I somehow set a default incorrectly somewhere.  I will have to default to saving to a .csv file and then importing, which works fine but is just annoying when a simple cut and paste was working before.

Comment: Did you try to reboot your pc?

Comment: Does using the "Text to Columns" wizard in Excel again making sure to select Delimited->Tab fix the issue?

Comment: What is the default destination for results set to in SSMS?  Go to Tools | Options | Query Results | General and look at the value in the drop-down.

Comment: 1.  Yes  2.  Theoretically, but the text is not delimited in any way so there's no way to tell where the column breaks without a lot of hassle  3.  It's set to Results to Grids

Answer (score 0):

If you use the text to columns feature in excel *before* the copy and paste from SQL, the pasted format will remember the settings you selected for the delimiter and use this.

If you run the text to columns now, and set it to be comma, and then try pasting your results to see if this fixes your issue.

What I am assuming is what @Tim Mylott has suggested, and that you currently have set to tabs or something that doesn't display 'user friendly'. Tabs don't appear when copied and pasted in the string format, but they are there behind the scenes, so the TTC feature will still work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this solution worked perfectly. My original pasted data became space-delimited when pasting into Excel, so I highlighted the first column, ran the Text-to-Columns wizard and deselected space and comma, leaving only tab. Then deleted out the original data and re-pasted it into Excel. No spaces!